# How to get the number of years and months based on the total?

Tags: c#

I want to calculate how many years and months based on the total. Here is what I have done so far.

```
int total = 23;
float test = total/12;

entYears.Text = //number of years here;
entMonths.Text = //number of months here;
```

Comment: Ideally you should use a `Timespan` to store a date range, but you'd need to start with something more accurate than "23 months", since the number of days in a month vary. If you can tell us where `23` comes from, we can help with a better design. Do you have a start date and end date by any chance?

Comment: @RufusL no its just the design I want to calculate how many years and months based on the total simple as that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of years will be `total/12`. On the other hand, months will be `total%12`.

A year is 12 months, so to get years you want to use the division. Months will be the “leftover” after you’ve calculated years, which is where modulus 12 comes into play.

23/12 will evaluate to 1, so 1 year. 23%12 will evaluate to 11. This means 23 is 1 year and 11 months.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) (`%`):

```
int total = 23;
int years = total / 12;
int months = total % 12;
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/BQTSL40742)